# join two table with two foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a table that contain user data

```
Users(userID, name , email ,......)
```

and i hava another table that contain :

```
Userfriends(UserFriendID,Fk_UserSendReqID,FK_UserRecieveReqID,IsAccepted,....)
```

in UserFriends table there is two foreign key that join this table with users table
i want write a query with linq that select friends of user with `userId=2`
i write this query but it is wrong

```
 var n = from u in DataContext.Context.Users
                join uf in DataContext.Context.UsersFriends
                on u.UserID equals uf.UserSendReqID
                join uf2 in DataContext.Context.UsersFriends
                on u.UserID equals uf2.UserRecieveReqID
                where (uf.UserSendReqID == 2|| uf.UserRecieveReqID == 2)
                && uf.IsAccepted == true
                select new
                {
                    name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are 2 foreign keys for `Users` table, you have to join `Users` table instead of `UsersFriends`

```
var userID = 2;
var n = from u in DataContext.Context.Users
            join uf in DataContext.Context.UsersFriends
            on u.UserID equals uf.UserSendReqID
            join u in DataContext.Context.Users
            on u2.UserID equals uf.UserRecieveReqID
            where (uf.UserSendReqID == userID || uf.UserRecieveReqID == userID)
            && uf.IsAccepted == true
            select new
            {
                //if UserSendReqID == userID, then select for u, else u2
                name = (uf.UserSendReqID == userID)
                             ? (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)
                             : (u2.FirstName + " " + u2.LastName)
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = DataContext.Context.Users
                   .Where(u=>DataContext.Context.UsersFriends
                            .Where(uf=>(uf.UserSendReqID == 2 ||
                                       uf.UserReceiveReqID == 2) && uf.IsAccepted)
                            .Any(uf=>uf.UserFriendID == u.userID))
                   .Select(u=> new {
                                 Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName                                     
                               });
```

Or using `Join`:

```
var n = DataContext.Context.Users
                   .Join(DataContext.Context.UsersFriends
                                    .Where(uf=>(uf.UserSendReqID == 2 ||
                                       uf.UserReceiveReqID == 2) && uf.IsAccepted),
                         x=>x.userID, x=>x.UserFriendID, (x,y)=>x)
                   .Select(u=> new {
                                 Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName                                     
                               });
```

expression query:

```
var n = from u in DataContext.Context.Users
        join uf in DataContext.Context.UsersFriends on u.userID equals uf.UserFriendID
        where (uf.UserSendReqID == 2 || uf.UserReceiveReqID == 2) && uf.IsAccepted
        select new {
                 Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
               };
```